# PHP Youtube Embed Can't Scroll

Tags: php, video, youtube, scroll, embed

I have a website where people can post videos and images.But when I click on a video to see I can't scroll anymore even if I stop the video. I using only firefox I want to know if is from me problem or I need to make some changes on website.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some code- it's not an usual error

Comment: I don't knw what code exactly to give you but here is website: literion.com , you can try to see if is problem with website or is just me.

Comment: wow, I wonder where I've seen that layout before :-o

Comment: :)) I guess you should pay 9gag some money for that :P

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking a little bit in your page source and you have a couple of `scrolling="no"` there.
You also have some other statements related to scrolling like
`$.scrollTo('.gag-link:eq('+(j)+')');`
Obviously, I couldn't analyze all your code, since it is a lot of it, but try taking a look at your statements that involve scolling